# Can all icons pinned to the start menu in Windows 10 be resized at once?

Tags: windows, start-menu

With the latest build of Windows 10 I can hide the "all apps" section of the start menu on Windows 10. I will pin many icons in the "Pinned tiles" section of the start menu. I going to resize almost all of them to small and few ones will be resized to medium or large. Instead of having to go one by one to resize them to samll, I want to resize them all at once to small and then resize to medium or large those few that need it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a way currently to resize all of the pinned apps in the Windows 10 Start Menu at once or in a batch.

Comment: How do you know this ?

Comment: I'm no genius, I'm just an above-average guesser. That, and I asked Google and found where others had asked he same thing. Oh, and I'm also running three different versions of Windows 10 on several different computers and none of them have a way to do what is being asked.

Comment: Key to the answer, though, is "currently". I assume it is possible to write an application that would be able to do this. That application has just not yet been written.